# Can't resize picture in CircleImageView

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, picasso, android-glide

I have this XML:

```xml
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:src="@drawable/ic_kitty_superhero"
    android:id="@+id/userAvatar"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    app:civ_border_color="@android:color/white" // just to show you wrong result
    app:civ_border_width="1dp" />
```

and this extension function to load image:

```kotlin
fun ImageView.loadImage(context: Context, url: String) {
    val resourceID = context.resources.getIdentifier(url, "drawable", context.packageName)
    if (resourceID != 0) { // if it's an image from drawable folder
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(resourceID)
            .fitCenter()
            .into(this)
    } else {
        Picasso.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .fit()
            .centerInside()
            .into(this)
    }
}
```

Since Picasso doesn't know how to work with `resourceID`, I need to use Glide or something similar like `this.setImageResource()`. But it's cannot execute transformation that I want.

[image]  [image]

In the first photo, everything looks the way I want, but it’s just used **ImageView** container.

In the second photo I use **CircleImageView** container and it no longer looks the way I would like - the ears are cropped in the photo.

Please, can you help me, how can I get the correct result?

**NOTE:** I **can't** use `.load(R.drawable.icon)` and I **can't** use the ImageView container (I can probably if make it circle somehow)

Comment: Try adding Android:scaleType: fitXY

Comment: @CodeREDInnovations, "The ScaleType is always CENTER_CROP and you'll get an exception if you try to change it" - info from [here](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView#limitations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using *ImageView* container and [Circle Transformation](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations) for Picasso